# Von Neumann's Trace Inequality for Multiple Matrices

Tags: matrices, inequality, trace

Von Neumann's trace inequality states that $|tr(AB)| \le \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sigma_i(A) \sigma_i(B)$ where $A, B$ are general square matrices with singular values $(\sigma_i(A)), (\sigma_i(B))$, respectively.

**Question**: does the analogous inequality hold for 3 (or more) matrices?

**Related**: If it were true, I would expect to find this generalization elsewhere. However, it seems to be proven in a slightly different form in Theorem 2 of [[Kristof 69]](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/j.2333-8504.1969.tb00744.x/pdf). When checking the reference, note (1) that $\lambda_i(A A^*) = \sigma_i(A)^2$ and (2) that $tr(ABC) \le tr(Z_1 diag(\sigma(A)) Z_2 diag(\sigma(B)) Z_3 diag(\sigma(C)))$ where $Z_i$ are unitary. The second claim can be easily argued via SVD and trace cycling. I would like somebody more knowledgable to point out my mistake to me. I haven't checked the proof in the paper.

Comment: I think the answer is stated in p 342 of <Inequalities: Theory of Majorization and Its Applications>, 2011, by Albert W. Marshall, Ingram Olkin, and Barry C. Arnold.